# C# Reflection Call Method with ref/Pointer Parameter

Tags: c#, pointers, reflection, ref

I want to call with reflection each Method of an Class but I cant call Methods with an pointer as Reference. Normally I just could pass null for each pointer I find and everything would be fine. The Problem is when the function trys to access my passed pointer. The pointer would be an reference to the memory address 0 and that is obviously an instant crash for my Program.
So I need to pass an pointer to an valid memory adress, but I dont know how I can create an pointer during runtime

A compressed Version of my Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new TestClass();
        var pointerMethod = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Test");
        var referenceMethod = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Test2");

        var pointerParameter = pointerMethod.GetParameters()[0];
        var referenceParameter = referenceMethod.GetParameters()[0];

        //Get the instance of the class that is referred by the pointer/reference
        var pointerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(pointerParameter.ParameterType.GetElementType());
        var referenceInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(referenceParameter.ParameterType.GetElementType());

        //Call the method and "cast" the char instance into an pointer
        pointerMethod.Invoke(obj, new[] {pointerInstance.GetType().MakePointerType()});
        referenceMethod.Invoke(obj, new[] { referenceInstance.GetType().MakeByRefType() });
     }
}
```

And TestClass:

```
public class TestClass
{
        unsafe public void Test(char* pointer)
        {

        }

        public void Test2(ref int reference)
        {

        }
}
```

I've always get the Exception "System.RuntimeType" cannot be converted to type 'System.Char*'
The weird thing is that pointerInstance.GetType().MakePointerType() returns a char*, exactly that what I have to pass into the function...

Comment: Your method declaration is invalid to start with - you haven't provided a parameter type. (`ref` is a modifier, not a type.) If you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, that would help a lot. Also, I suggest you try with *just* a ref parameter or *just* a pointer parameter - otherwise you won't know which one is failing...

Comment: I've edited my post and compressed the code

Comment: But still not included a short but complete program I can simply copy, paste, compile and run. And does the `ref` version work? If so, remove it - it would be better to concentrate on *one* problem rather than showing two.

Comment: The ref version throws the same Exception. And the program is complete you just have to paste it into an main function...^^

Comment: Also note that you appear to be trying to pass the *types* as the arguments - instead of passing the *values*. The second argument to `Invoke` is meant to be the arguments to pass, not the types of the parameters...

Comment: If it doesn't contain a class and method declaration, it's not complete. Why should every person trying to help you need to do that work, when you can do it *once*? It's *really* not that hard, and as you're the person asking for help, you should be the one putting in the effort.

Answer (score 10):

First, let's separate this into pointer vs `ref` - they're handled slightly differently.

It's not clear what pointer value you *expected* the method to receive - particularly as the value you passed to `Invoke` was a type, not an instance of the type - but you should use [`Pointer.Box`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.pointer.box):

```
using System.Reflection;

class TestPointer
{    
    unsafe static void Main()
    {
        char c = 'x';
        char* p = &c;
        object boxedPointer = Pointer.Box(p, typeof(char*));

        var method = typeof(TestPointer).GetMethod("Foo");
        method.Invoke(null, new[] { boxedPointer });
        Console.WriteLine("After call, c = {0}", c);
    }

    public static unsafe void Foo(char *pointer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", *pointer);
        *pointer = 'y';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Received: x
After call, c = y
```

For `ref` parameters, it's slightly simpler - you just allow for normal boxing, and the argument array is changed:

```
using System.Reflection;

class TestRef
{    
    unsafe static void Main()
    {
        var method = typeof(TestRef).GetMethod("Foo");
        var args = new object[] { 10 };
        method.Invoke(null, args);
        Console.WriteLine("After call, args[0] = {0}", args[0]);
    }

    public static unsafe void Foo(ref int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", x);
        x = 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: @leppie: I'd never even seen it before today :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I totaly forgot that I passed Type's as parameter.But I still have a question, what if I do not know which type of pointer I have? Like in my Example I only have a Object representing the Type

Comment: @Djeurissen: If you don't even know the type, where are you expecting to get a value from?

Comment: Sorry my fault. I know the type but only during runtime.

Comment: @Djeurissen: So where do you expect to get the *value* from?

Comment: The value for the pointer to reference? I use Activator.CreateInstance(type.GetElementType());

Comment: @Djeurissen: Now, a value for the pointer itself - not sure what you mean by "pointer to reference". You can't create a pointer from nothing... I really think you should take a step back and thing about what you're trying to achieve... it's entirely non-obvious at the moment.

Comment: Type x = typeof(char*); var valueForPointer = Activatior.GetInstance(x.GetElementType());

Comment: @Djeurissen: That will create a `char`, and box it. That won't create a pointer. And it still feels like you're not taking a step back to consider the context. It would really help if you would explain *why* you're trying to do this - by editing the question.

Comment: @Djeurissen: Not really. You haven't given any background for *why* you want to call this method, or why you're doing so with reflection. Do you care about the value that the pointer refers to? I suspect some ugliness may be required to handle this, given that generics won't work cleanly with pointers. (Do you only need to handle pointers to primitive types, or arbitrary structs?)

Comment: I want to call each Method to test if it returns an Exception. I know that sounds a little bit weird, because I pass crap values to the Methods. But I just want to create a Method which can be used to test if any Method in any class returns an unexpected Exception. Its just a generic aproach for Unit Testing.

Comment: @Djeurissen: Sounds like a bad idea to me. You've already seen that if you pass in a null pointer, and the method dereferences it, you'll get an exception. The same is true for managed types too - you shouldn't rely on every type having a parameterless constructor you can call, and every method being callable with some arbitrary value. (Suppose you have a method which has to take non-zero values - how are you going to know *not* to pass in 0?)