# C# Get Instance of type char*

Tags: c#, pointers, runtime, instance

is it possible to get an instance of an pointer during runtime? 
Something like:

```
Type x = typeof(char*);
```

How do I get a instance of this pointer? The problem is that I only have a Object with an Type inside. And I know that the Type is a pointer. But now I need a instance of the pointer.

Comment: `typeof(char).MakePointerType()`

Comment: This sounds a little odd - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is my last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911369/c-sharp-reflection-call-method-with-ref-pointer-parameter/30913365?noredirect=1#comment49864555_30913365 I want to use Reflection to call a Method with an Pointer as Parameter. The Problem is I only know the Type during runtime. Jon Skeet suggested that I should use Pointer.Box, the Problem is I need an void* Instance to use the method. But as I said, i dont have one during runtime...

Comment: The only valid reason you could have for using pointers (other than very obscure unsafe code for optimisation purposes)  is if you are calling unmanaged code. Are you calling unmanaged code?

Comment: `IntPtr` should be used for passing pointers as objects for reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

```
Type typeChar = typeof(char);
Type ptrChar = typeChar.MakePointerType(); // char*
```

and back:

```
if (ptrChar.IsPointer)
{
    Type typeChar2 = ptrChar.GetElementType(); // char
}
```

But perhaps what you want is something different:

```
public class TestBool
{
    unsafe public void Test(bool* pointer)
    {
        *pointer = true;
    }

    public void Test2(ref bool reference)
    {
        reference = true;
    }
}

public class TestChar
{
    unsafe public void Test(char* pointer)
    {
        *pointer = 'A';
    }

    public void Test2(ref char reference)
    {
        reference = 'B';
    }
}

public static void TestPointer(object obj, Type parType)
{
    var pointerMethod = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Test");

    Type parType2;

    // Non-blittable types aren't directly supported. 
    // See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx
    // We cheat a little.
    if (parType == typeof(bool))
    {
        parType2 = typeof(byte);
    }
    else if (parType == typeof(char))
    {
        parType2 = typeof(short);
    }
    else if (parType.IsEnum)
    {
        parType2 = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(parType);
    }
    else
    {
        parType2 = parType;
    }

    object obj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(parType2);
    GCHandle handle = default(GCHandle);

    try
    {
        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(obj2, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        pointerMethod.Invoke(obj, new object[] { handle.AddrOfPinnedObject() });
    }
    finally
    {
        if (handle.IsAllocated)
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }

    if (parType == typeof(bool))
    {
        obj2 = (byte)obj2 != 0;
    }
    else if (parType == typeof(char))
    {
        obj2 = (char)(short)obj2;
    }
    else if (parType.IsEnum)
    {
        obj2 = Enum.ToObject(parType, obj2);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(obj2);
}

public static void TestReference(object obj, Type parType)
{
    var referenceMethod = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Test2");

    object obj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(parType);
    var pars = new object[] { obj2 };

    referenceMethod.Invoke(obj, pars);

    Console.WriteLine(pars[0]);
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    {
        var obj = new TestBool();
        TestPointer(obj, typeof(bool));
        TestReference(obj, typeof(bool));
    }

    {
        var obj = new TestChar();
        TestPointer(obj, typeof(char));
        TestReference(obj, typeof(char));
    }
}
```

See how for the `TestPointer`, ignoring some problems with non-blittable types, I simply use `GCHandle` to obtain a pointer to the value and then pass it directly to the method. No unsafe code necessary :-)

For `TestReference` it is much easier: I only need to create the parameters array separately, and then the CLR will put in that array the modified values.

Comment: @Djeurissen As suggested by Skeet, there is `Pointer.Unbox(ptr)` that will return a `void*`

Comment: Sure if I had an pointer before. But Pointer.Unbox(' '); wont give me an char pointer

Comment: @Djeurissen It isn't clear what you have... try writing a working example.

Comment: @Djeurissen As `skeet` wrote, where would you have the value? Another `object`?

Comment: Lets say I have a Type variable Type x = typeof(char*); with x.GetElementName() I get the referenced Type. In this case char. Now I can create an Instance of char like this Activator.CreateInstance(x.GetElementType()); All I have to do now, is to get an Pointer to the return value of Activator.CreateInstance. But how? Maybe I do not understand your question...

Comment: @Djeurissen I don't think you can... You can't take the address of a boxed value, and `Activator.CreateInstance` will create the value and box it. Still I do feel that this is a false problem. You can create a piece of blank memory and have his address without problem. You can then pass it to a C/C++ method and let them fill it. You don't need to create a `char`. You only need to create a space of 2 or more bytes of memory.

Comment: @Djeurissen Changed the response. See if this is what you wanted